# VBA and Active Directory: Windows group visible in manual search dialog but VBA script throws error

Tags: vba, excel, active-directory

For the syntax: `GetObject("WinNT://<server>/<group>,group")`, found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321538)(VBA code also at the link) , the VBA code runs fine and returns all the user names in the group.

Problem: For some of the existing group names, which we can verify manually, VBA throws error saying,

```
-2147024843 
Automation error
The network path was not found.
```

Comment: Store it in a variable for use in the function?

Comment: tried that. also replacing spaces with quotes. enclosed the whole group name in quotes. nothing works.

Comment: What about trying to replace spaces with character code `Chr(32)`?

Comment: Did you try to enclose it in square braces `[group ]`?

Comment: no [group] is also of no good use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this as its very weird and absolutely rare to happen.

So this error/issue of missing Windows Group happened because of the compatibility issue in Active Directory servers. After an update alot of the servers got upgraded to Win 2K+ (Yes, right Windows 2000, nothing fancy.)

But some the servers remained on older configuration and so does the names of Windows Groups on those servers. Now when we use WinMgmt queries on AD servers, they go by-default to the latest ones.  So even though you can see those windows group names manually here: RUN --> `%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe dsquery,OpenQueryWindow` (this loads the Active Directory search dialog), the Active Directory Service Interfaces, just throw automation error.

So the only work around that I have figured so far is that once a Windows group name throws automation error, we need to resend the query and this time we instead of `Logon Name`  we use the AD property called `Logon Name (pre-Windows 2000)` and it just works.

You can see the `Logon Name (pre-Windows 2000)` property of any windows group by selecting the same in `View --> Custom Columns..` inside the active directory search dialog.

I know the answer is not very straight forward and conscise but I have very limited knowledge of Active Directory. Just posted it so that some one may fine it useful in future.